# Whenever I run my android app it immediatly closes on my real phone

Tags: android, kotlin

So far I havent written any kotlin code in android studio but whenever I try to run the default app on my real phone, it immediately closes. Do any of you have suggestions on how to fix this. Heres my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="@android:dimen/thumbnail_width"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Koji!"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thx

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-resolve-app-crashes-in-android-studio

Comment: Examine Logcat to see the stack trace associated with your crash.